# MFC ODBC- How can I know the result of ExecuteSQL() is "NO DATA FOUND"?

Tags: mfc, odbc

In odbc, SQLExecDirect() has return value, so I could know there is no data using "SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND".

But in MFC odbc, ExecuteSQL() has no return value, so I don't know whether the result of ExecuteSQL() is "NO DATA FOUND" or not.

How can I do?

Comment: [CDatabase::ExecuteSQL](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/67cze9b7%28v=vs.71%29) _ExecuteSQL does not return data records_ You need to use 'CRecordSet' to read and write records.

Comment: But as far as i know cRecordSet.open() only used in 'select' sql. I need in insert update or delete....

Comment: [CDatabase::ExecuteSQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bd0de70a-e3c3-4441-bcaa-bbf434426ca8.aspx#cdatabase__executesql) reports errors by throwing a `CDBException` exception. That's MFC trying to be C++.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are after. [CRecordSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92bcy0kw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) does all those things and you don't have to use SQL. It is intended to give you direct access to a database without SQL. Download one or two of the examples to see how it works.